# gitlab page deployed but only visible thing is non0working navbar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite

The pipeline has passed for deployment for gitlab pages however the only thing I see is a non-working navbar. I am using vite + react for my portfolio. This is my second deployed project (its actually my portfolio) and following the same steps as before led me to this. I have no console errors and I am out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated. attached files are: docker compose (not sure what this would have to do with anything), vite.config, and app.jsx. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6Z7W.png)[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oixzg.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3seR.png)

This is the non-working page. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wqajl.png)

I believe it has to do with my routes. Ive tried a truckload of different things yet have been unsuccessful. Im sure its something very simple.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.